React MUI conditional isChecked checkbox
I'm utilizing a Checkbox component from the MUI library within my React application. I need this checkbox to be dynamically checked or unchecked based on a condition.
The condition depends on the item being viewed. Essentially, my application layout consists of a list of items on the left. Upon clicking an item, a form on the right displays with pre-populated values specific to that item. Now, I'm attempting to use a boolean property within a state variable to manage the checkbox's checked status dynamically.
However, I encounter an error message:
MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized. To suppress this warning, opt to use a controlled SwitchBase.
The checkbox fails to re-render dynamically. Any insights would be appreciated.
TIA.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel } from '@mui/material';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function YourComponent({ item }) {
  const [checkedItem, setCheckedItem] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({ defaultValues});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (item) {
      setCheckedItem(item.booleanProperty);
    }
  }, [item]);

  return (
    // other code..
    <FormControlLabel
      control={<Checkbox defaultChecked={checkedItem}/>}
      label="label"
      {...register("item")}
    />
    // other code..
  );
}

export default YourComponent;


I don't know where the {...register('item')} comes from, but when I leave that out it is working fine in my case.
I only changed the type of the item that is given as a prop.
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel } from '@mui/material';

interface IItem {
    booleanProperty: boolean;
}

function YourComponent(item: IItem) {
    const [checkedItem, setCheckedItem] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (item) {
            setCheckedItem(item.booleanProperty);
        }
    }, [item]);

    return (
    // other code..
        <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox defaultChecked={checkedItem}/>}
            label="label"
            // {...register('item')}
        />
    // other code..
    );
}

export default YourComponent;


My mistake, I left out that I'm using react-hook-form. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Okay, then I added this: const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm<{ item: boolean; }>({ defaultValues: { item: false }});
below the checkedItem state and it works for me.
